# nodemon restarting repeatedly

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

nodemon keeps restarting without changes.

I tried

> fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1

in open console in an admin mode.

also tried

> npm update

I didn't edit any code except package.json to use nodemon

node version : 12.18.1

** update

without file name

[image]

with file name

[image]

Comment: Is your programm write into a file inside your project?

Comment: A *Hint* you can start nodemon with the flag -v this will display what the restart had triggered

Comment: @Alex Where do i need to put -v in?
i tried npm start -v and it just shows the version of npm

Comment: If you type `nodemon --help` you will see: `-V, --verbose ... show detail on what is causing restarts.`  Try that first.  But most likely your code is writing to a file in your project's directory.  (it's capital `-V` and it goes in your package.json in the `start` script as a command line argument to `nodemon`)

Comment: `nodemon -V <yourfilename>`

Comment: tried it, and it showed some process id (chilld pid) but  I cant find the problem in it.

Comment: this would be a useful information. Can you update your question and add this verbose output of nodemon to it?

Comment: Most likely there is some file changed on startup (i.e. when you build typescript, or write logs, anything). You should find it and put it to ignore files.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The problem was

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
},
```

I needed to add ./bin/www

Still it was a complicated question for me